# Laravel guards, gates and policies

Tags: laravel, authorization

I am building a market place, and I have three guards: user, business, and admin. each guard have a route for its dashboard: /, /business, /admin.

I wanted to redirect the user to these routes based on the guard, but I do not know how to do that. Investigating, I found that exists "gates" and "policies". Now I am confused about how I should manage the user types.

Can someone explain when to use guards, gates, or policies?

I did it that way because I do not need the same information for each user type, so I put them in different tables. That made sense for me, but now I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to configure different user roles and permissions I use this package

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

It immediately creates a database structure and has middlewares for checks, it makes things very easy